# Sentence split using spacy sentenizer

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am using spaCy's sentencizer to split the sentences.

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English()
sbd = nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer')
nlp.add_pipe(sbd)

text="Please read the analysis. (You'll be amazed.)"
doc = nlp(text)

sents_list = []
for sent in doc.sents:
   sents_list.append(sent.text)

print(sents_list)
print([token.text for token in doc])
```

OUTPUT

```
['Please read the analysis. (', 
"You'll be amazed.)"]

['Please', 'read', 'the', 'analysis', '.', '(', 'You', "'ll", 'be', 
'amazed', '.', ')']
```

Tokenization is done correctly but I am not sure it's not splitting the 2nd sentence along with ( and taking this as an end in the first sentence.

Answer (score 5):

I have tested below code with en_core_web_lg and en_core_web_sm model and performance for sm model are similar to using sentencizer. (lg model will hit the performance).

Below custom boundaries only works with sm model and behave different splitting with lg model.

```
nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
def set_custom_boundaries(doc):
    for token in doc[:-1]:
        if token.text == ".(" or token.text == ").":
            doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = True
        elif token.text == "Rs." or token.text == ")":
            doc[token.i+1].is_sent_start = False
    return doc

nlp.add_pipe(set_custom_boundaries, before="parser")
doc = nlp(text)

for sent in doc.sents:
 print(sent.text)
```

Comment: Any specific reason to inclue  before="parser" in add_pipe?

Comment: You want sentence splitting to happen before the parsing can happen over the sentence boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

The `sentencizer` is a very fast but also very minimal sentence splitter that's not going to have good performance with punctuation like this. It's good for splitting texts into sentence-ish chunks, but if you need higher quality sentence segmentation, use the `parser` component of an English model to do sentence segmentation.

Comment: As per spacy documentation -the Sentencizer lets you implement a simpler, rule-based strategy that doesn’t require a statistical model to be loaded. https://spacy.io/api/sentencizer#_title.if go with custom component i have to load model like - spacy.load("en_core_web_sm"). 
Will it cause any performance issue cause i am using this Sentencizer in chatbot project where the response is split and return to the user in very short time?

Comment: Yes, the parser will be a lot slower, but any more accurate method is going to be slower. If you don't have that many additional rules/cases to handle and they're not too complicated, you can also create your own rule-based sentencizer component pretty easily. (I would like to implement a statistical model for sentence segmentation that would be somewhere in between the sentencizer and the parser in terms of speed and accuracy, but it's just a sketch at this point.)